# Mongoose accessing 'this' in validator is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema, this

I have the following schema:

```
const MediaSchema = new Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: val => this[val] != null,
    },
  },
  image: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'PostPicture',
  },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Essentially, I want to validate that if `type` is set to image, then the image field has to exist on the document.

However, in the validator for type `this` is returning undefined. I swear I had this working before. Can anyone offer any insight?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `validator` is an arrow function and arrow function does not have its own `this` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

Comment: The amount of times I've been bitten by this... Changing it to a regular function did the trick, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

you can access by val keyward without this keyword like

```js
validate: {
      validator: val => val !== null
    },
```